# I have 3 divs and they're wrapping instead of pushing right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a dashboard and have 3 divs like in the example below. At a certain screen size, the left-sidebar collapses and a button appears on the screen to toggle the sidebar, similar to the [Bootstrap Off-Canvas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/offcanvas/#) example.

When I toggle the left-sidebar, the right-sidebar wraps under the middle-column.

What can I do to prevent the right-sidebar from wrapping and instead have it push right and crop/hide the overflow?

Thanks!

```
   <div class="container-fluid main-content">
    <div class="left-sidebar">Content of Left Sidebar</div>
    <div class="middle-content">Content of Middle</div>
    <div class="right-side">Content of Right Sidebar</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          Content of Left Sidebar
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
         Content of Middle
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
         Content of Right Sidebar
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

simplify your layout settings with grid classes